# What's the way to access getMintInfo on v2

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

Token class was removed on 2.0 whats the current way to getMintInfo I cant see it exported at https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/

```
export async function getTokenMint(
  connection: Connection,
  tokenMintPubkey: PublicKey,
): Promise<MintInfo | undefined> {
  // @ts-ignore
  const token = new Token(connection, tokenMintPubkey, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, null);
  return token.getMintInfo();
}
```

Found the answer exported as `getMint` `from spl-token`
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getMint

Answer (score 2):

resolved:

Found the answer exported as getMint from spl-token

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getMint